# Duplicate data source error PowerBI

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, powerbi

I'm running into a "Duplicate data source error" while trying to add sources to my on-premises gateway in PowerBI. The sources causing this error are two databases sitting on the same Azure Sql Server. All of the credentials and connection strings are the same with the exception of the database name. Does anyone with PowerBi experience know why this is happening? Am I going to have to merge these two databases because of a limitation with the PowerBi software? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you adding the Azure databases to the gateway? You can connect to them without it?

Comment: We need to refresh the sources automatically via the gateway. You can connect to nearly anything in powerbi without a gateway

Comment: Yes, I know, but you don’t have to add them to the on-premise gateway, since they’re not on-premise. Of course, you can still configure datarefresh.

Comment: I just split the databases to two different servers and the problem is gone. Still would be nice to use the same server for multiple databases.

Comment: Ok. Glad you worked it out. I still don't understand why you must add them to the on-premise gateway, Maybe we're just confusing terms here. Good luck!